# Type of sentence and it's parts

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax, parts-of-speech

What type of sentence is it? What members of sentence are here?

> It(song) was no strain on the voice, and I guessed that Margaret knew what
>   she was doing when she chose it.

My observations:
It's a **compound sentence**.There are **5** clauses:1) It was no strain on the voice, 2) I guessed 3) that Margaret knew, 4) what she was doing, 5)when she chose it.

1)*It* - formal subject.

*Was no strain* - the compound nominal predicate

*On her voice* - the prepositional object.

2) *I* - simple subject

*guessed* - simple predicate.

3) that Margaret knew - is it some kind of object clause?

*Margaret* -simple subject.

*Knew* - simple predicate

*That* - ?

4)what she was doing - object clause? What does it consist of?

*She* -subj

*Was doing* - simlpe verbal predicate(past continious)

*What* - ?

5)when she chose it - adverbial clause of time.

*She* - subj,

*Chose* - predicate,

*It*- object,

*when* - ?

As you can see,my grammar is preaty bad,please,help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is really a nice and thorough analysis!  Now to your questions:

> ... and I guessed **that** Margaret knew...

**that** -- subordinating conjunction.

> ... Margaret knew **what** she was doing...

**what** -- relative pronoun, the object of "do" (was doing).

> ... **when** she chose it.

**when** -- subordinating conjunction.

Comment: Victor, as you are familiar with the way **russian** grammarians treat parts of sentense(attributes,adverbal modifiers),could you help me with this question? http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72632/where-are-the-objects-and-the-attributes-in-these-sentences

Comment: I wish I were half as decent with my English grammar as I am with Russian... but I'll try.  What didn't you like about the answer you already received?