# Where are the objects and the attributes in these sentences

Tags: prepositional-phrases, possessives, objects, adverbial-phrases

Where are the **objects** and the **attributes** in these sentences?

> There was no reply,
>   but in a moment
>   Miss Glaser began to play the opening bars of one of Schumann’s songs.
>   It was no strain on the voice,
>   and I guessed that Miss Glaser knew what she was doing when she chose it.
>   La Falterona began to sing, in an undertone,
>   but as she heard the sounds come from her lips
>   and found that they were clear and pure
>   she let herself go.

I'm particularly interested in "in a moment", "of one of Schumann’s songs", "from her lips" and "no strain on the  voice".

**The attribute** is a secondary part of the sentence which characterizes person or non-person expressed by the headword either qualitatively, quantitatively, or from the point of view of situation.
http://5fan.ru/wievjob.php?id=47143 and http://5fan.ru/wievjob.php?id=46987

Comment: *Attribute* is not a technical term used in the grammars I'm familiar with. Could you provide a definition? ... The phrases you single out are all *preposition phrases*, consisting of a preposition and an object noun phrase.

Comment: In English the attribute is called [grammatical modifier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier).

Comment: I'm not sure about this: 1) Was no strain - the compound nominal predicate - maybe the predicate is "was ...strain",and "no" (as it's an adjective) will be an attribute. 2) On her voice - the prepositional object - natives call it simply prepostional phrase,but what parts of sentense is it consist of?

Comment: In "*was no strain*" the "*no strain*" is a "**subject complement**" or "**predicative complement**".  The subject is "it", which is a relative pronoun referring to the noun "song".  We can rewrite it "**The song was easy** on her voice..."

Comment: "On her voice" is a prepositional phrase.  "Her voice" is an object of the preposition "on".  Together they make an adverbial phrase modifying "strain" (strain where?  strain on her voice.)

Comment: Sorry but these questions get bogged down in complicated things that often have nothing to do with the question, which, here, should be rewritten or clarified. And then the discussion gets into complicated grammar terminology questions. So boring.

Answer (score 1):

The usual English term for the Latin term attribute is modifier. A modifier is a subelement of a noun, such as article, adjective, relative clause etc.

"in a moment" is no attribute/modifier. It is no subelement of a noun, but a sentence part (a when-indication), ie an adverbial group or adverbial sentence part.

"of one of Schubert's songs" is an attribute/ modifier of "the opening bars".

"She heard the sounds come from her lips": "from her lips" (a where-from indication) is an adverbial sentence part.

Comment: "in a moment" is no modifier as it is not connected with a noun. It is an adverbial of time acting as an additional sentence part. -  An attribute/modifier to " songs" would be wonderful or a shortened relative clause: one of Schubert's wonderful songs written in the year xx.

Comment: Daisy, you should really study the parts of a sentence. http://www.english-language-grammar-guide.com/parts-of-a-sentence.html

Comment: Adverbial modifier can modify a verb: she began to sing WHEN/HOW SOON?  - **"in a moment"**. Am I wrong again?

Comment: No, you're not wrong.  'rogermue' also calls it "adverbial group" (phrase). And yes, it modifies/defines "began".